# Access OpenCV two cameras with single USB port (stereo camera)

Tags: image, opencv, camera, rgb, vision

I am using the OVRVision camera (http://ovrvision.com/). It basically consists of two cameras, but on one USB port. They both have their own device Id in OpenCV, however, I can't open both at the same time:

```
videoCaptureLeft = new VideoCapture(1);
videoCaptureRight = new VideoCapture(2);
```

videoCaptureRight.isOpened() returns false. It works with two webcams on two separate ports. Is there any special functionality to access rgb data of stereo cameras?

Comment: Hi, Did you ever solve this problem? I am having a very similar one with the ELP-1MP2CAM001